# hybrid PKE scheme CCA2 insecurity

Tags: public-key, semantic-security, chosen-ciphertext-attack, hybrid-encryption

I'm reading ["An Efficient CCA2-Secure Variant of the McEliece Cryptosystem in the standard model" by Rastaghi](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0347.pdf) which states:

> As we know, in hybrid PKE schemes XOR alone cannot perfectly hide
>   challenge bit to the CCA2 adversary

1. The author does not define hybrid PKE schemes. What is their definition?
2. *Why* is it that XOR alone cannot perfectly hide challenge bit to the CCA2 adversary in hybrid PKE schemes?

Comment: 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem $\;$

Comment: Unless you have a good reason, I wouldn't worry too much about that paper. Why not read something else, like Bernstein, Lange and Peters (http://cr.yp.to/codes/mceliece-20080807.pdf) and its references?

Comment: @K.G Why wouldn't worry too much about that paper?

Comment: You learn more by reading better papers.

Answer (score 1):

> The author does not define hybrid PKE schemes. What is their
>   definition?

A hybrid public-key encryption scheme is a scheme that uses public-key encryption along with symmetric encryption to gain speed advantages for long messages.

The usual instantiation is to simply encrypt a key for the symmetric scheme and prepend the resulting cipher text. The more modern approach is to choose a random element from the PKE scheme's message space and encrypt it. Then use the hash of said element as the key for the symmetric scheme. This is called the KEM/DEM approach and allows for easier usage of elliptic curves (see [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECIES)) and code-based crypto (see [McBits by Bernstein](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/610.pdf) et al).

> *Why* is it that XOR alone cannot perfectly hide challenge bit to the CCA2 adversary in hybrid PKE schemes?

This means that the following scheme isn't CCA2 secure. **Encrypt** by choosing a random key from the PKE's message space use this key as one-time-pad, prepend the random key - encrypted with the PKE. **Decrypt** by decrypting the random key with the PKE and then use the result to decrypt the data with the OTP. Note: The OTP could be replaced by a stream cipher and the key may also be the result of a key-derivation function.

You see what is missing here? The message is not authenticated.

Say you're given a cipher text $c$ for an unknown message $m$ to be decrypted (if you can you win the CCA2 experiment). Suppose further that $c=(E_{PK}(k),H(k)\oplus m)$ which is standard construction for this. Note that $H(k)=k$ is allowed. Now randomly choose a $r$ of length $||m||$ and compute $c'=(E_{PK}(k),H(k)\oplus m\oplus r)$. Note that $c\neq c'$. Now query the decryption oracle for $c'$ and obtain $m'=m\oplus r$. Now finally reconstruct the message $m=m'\oplus r$ and you have "won" the CCA2 experiment.